# convert codes from swift to obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i was following someones instructions on how to do a login in xcode 6.1 using json, etc.

his link is:http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2014/07/login-signup-screen-tutorial-xcode-6-swift-ios-8-json/

he has code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    } else {
        self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString
    }
}
```

this code is added on the "main" controller. It will skip this controller if there isnt an authentication, prompting the user to sign in.

my "main" controller is in obj c with a whole bunch of codes that i will then have to translate or recode.

how can i use that code in obj c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C translation:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int isLoggedIn = (int)[prefs integerForKey:@"ISLOGGEDIN"];
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto_login" sender:self];
    } else {
        self.usernameLabel.text = [prefs valueForKey:@"USERNAME"];
    }
}
```

Comment: TNX! worked like a charm